# How to change Ionic Action Sheet position?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The Action Sheet is a slide-up panel that lets the user choose from a set of options. I want that but I need the options to pop-up in the middle of the screen, not the bottom.

I have tried to use $ionicPopup instead but they don't offer options like an Action Sheet, just alerts and confirmation boxes.

Either I change where does the Action Sheet or I change the what the $ionicPopup display.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option may be to design an [$ionicModal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) that has the options you are looking for.

As far as I know the Action Sheet cannot be re-positioned and the $ionicPopup seems to function like an alert or confirmation box. $ionicModal appears much more customizable.